# Accessing route in middleware using Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a `user.save` route (below) in my Golang API that can be used to `create` and `update` a user depending on whether an `id` was provided in the request object. The route uses the `auth` middleware which other routes do too.

```
api.POST("/user.save", auth(), user.Save())
api.POST("/user.somethingElse", auth(), user.SomethingElse())
```

Here is my middleware:

```
func auth() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        //I would like to know here if user.save was the route called
        //do authy stuff
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that if I can detect in the `auth` middleware whether the `user.save` route was called I can then check to see if an `id` was included and decide whether to continue or return.

Comment: I would change my routes to be a little more REST like. something like: `POST /users` would create a user and `PUT /users/{userID}` would update the user. Then you could apply the appropriate middleware to each route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could check the url from the auth handler. The actual request is on the context, so it's as easy as:

```
if c.Request.URL.Path == "/user.save" {
    // Do your thing
}
```

Another solution is to parameterize your auth middleware, something like this:

```
api.POST("/user.save", auth(true), user.Save())
api.POST("/user.somethingElse", auth(false), user.SomethingElse())

func auth(isUserSave bool) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if isUserSave {
            // Do your thing
        }
    }
}
```